# Spring batch remote chunking

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am trying to implement a remote chunking in spring batch with FlatFileItemReader, a custom writer and a custom processor. Can anyone please help me with the xml config for this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find XML config samples in the following repos:

- https://github.com/chrisjs/remote-chunking
- https://github.com/ghillert/spring-batch-integration-sample/tree/master/payment-import-remote-chunking

And Java config samples here:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples#remote-chunking-sample
- https://github.com/mminella/scaling-demos/tree/master/remote-chunking

Comment: The chrisjs link is broken